# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar

Tags: java, ubuntu-touch

I've made a mistake by:

> "sudo rm -rf /usr/share/java"

Now, every check version by

> "java -version"

the output messages is:

> "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   agent library failed to init: instrument"

My question:

How can I solve it for check java -version?

Update (1): by apply "sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java6-installer", the output:

> :~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java6-installer
>
> [sudo] password for evergreen:
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0 B/21.0 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   Preconfiguring packages ...
>   (Reading database ... 256954 files and directories currently installed.)
>
> Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java6-installer_6u45-0~webupd8~8_all.deb ...
>   oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
>   Unpacking oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) over (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
>   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
>   Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
>   Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
>   Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
>   Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
>   Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
>   Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk6-installer/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>   Removing outdated cached downloads...
>   Unpacking...
>   Checksumming...
>   Extracting...
>   UnZipSFX 5.50 of 17 February 2002, by Info-ZIP (Zip-Bugs@lists.wku.edu).
>      creating: jdk1.6.0_45/
>      creating: jdk1.6.0_45/db/
>      creating: jdk1.6.0_45/db/bin/
>     inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/db/bin/ij
>   .....................................................................................................................................................
>   Creating jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/deploy.jar
>
> Done.
>   ......................................................................................................................................
>
> update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
>
> update-binfmts: warning: current package is oracle-java6, but binary format already installed by openjdk-7
>
> Oracle JDK 6 installed
>   Oracle JRE 6 browser plugin installed
>
> xxxxx@xxx:~$ java -version
>
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   agent library failed to init: instrument

Comment: What about reinstalling java with `apt-get install --reinstall PACKAGENAME`? What Java did you use? Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java6-installer: as above update, no difference. I'm noticed with the message: "update-binfmts: warning: current package is oracle-java6, but binary format already installed by openjdk-7", may this is the core, but don't know how to solve.
I'm using the "oracle-java6-installer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a search for all packages for the path `/usr/share/java` in the standard language (English):

```
LANG=C apt-file search  /usr/share/java/ | awk -F": " '{print $1}' | sort -u | xargs apt-cache policy | grep -P -B 1 "Installed:\s[^(]"
```

With this command, you see a list of installed packages. Install these packages again with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package_name>
```

---

Sample output:

```
% LANG=C apt-file search  /usr/share/java/ | awk -F": " '{print $1}' | sort -u | xargs apt-cache policy | grep -P -B 1 "Installed:\s[^(]"

gettext:
  Installed: 0.19.2-2ubuntu1
--
gettext-base:
  Installed: 0.19.2-2ubuntu1
--
java-common:
  Installed: 0.52
--
libatk-wrapper-java:
  Installed: 0.30.5-1
--
libcommons-collections3-java:
  Installed: 3.2.1-8
--
libcommons-dbcp-java:
  Installed: 1.4-5ubuntu1
--
libcommons-pool-java:
  Installed: 1.6-2
--
libecj-java:
  Installed: 3.10.1-1
--
libservlet3.0-java:
  Installed: 7.0.56-2
--
libtomcat7-java:
  Installed: 7.0.56-2
--
ure:
  Installed: 4.4.2-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Super: for errors of missing is solved, as my update(2) above. My quest No.2 is still staying, could we also treat it?

Comment: This problem is a completely different and stands in no connection with the deletion of the files. Please be fair and create for this problem, a new question. I'll just watch this question then. :)

Comment: Agree!, I'm going to create new topic, will be updated.

Comment: A.B: my new topic is in: "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem. I solved it by installing libc6-dev-amd64.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-amd64
```

If still doesn't work, try to launch the installer in root mode:

```
sudo ./install
```